# Derivation of muon decay width in Fermi effective theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, weak-interaction

I'm reading [the article "Theory of the Fermi interaction" by Feynman and Gell-Mann](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/3514/) and encountered the following formula for lifetime of a muon:

$$\tau = \frac {192 \pi^3} {G_F^2 m_{\mu}^5}$$

It is not derived in the text of the article. Could someone point me out to a pedagogical derivation of this formula using Fermi's effective theory?

Comment: In general we prefer a link to an abstract page rather than directly to a document.  It is also useful to state the title, author(s) and a reference code if possible as links can go dead.